# Live filtering of a backbone.js view?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a table view of a backbone.js collection (loaded via json) of over 100 employees.

What I am trying to create is a "live search" (more like a "filter") field for users that, as they type, narrows the list to names that match what they are typing (probably >3 characters).

In other words, if they were to type "joh" anyone whose name is John or last name is Johnson would be on the list, and everyone else hidden.

I have done this in Actionscript, but am new to backbone.

Comment: Do you have a separate view for the table view and each row in the table.. Will will helpful if you can provide some code

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this plugin: [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/download/). It implements a search box that makes what you want to do. Here you have an example: [Example](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I'd rather do in in backbone rather than add another plugin.  Plus, it seems not to work and I think it's because the table is not yet populated when it's called. I will look at it further.